# Create a file in /system directory

Tags: android, system, root

I want to create a file in the /system directory. I think that directory is "protected" and the phone must be rooted to access and create to it.
I used this simple code to create a file in /system but nothing is created:

```
File file = new File("/system", "test.prop");
```

How can i solve that problem?
Thank you for your help.

Comment: Why do you want to create a file in the system directory?

Comment: @Franziskus Karsunke:I created a ROM and want to make for it a script. This script i want it to be located in /system directory. Is that possible ?

Comment: Only if the device is rooted.

Comment: @Franziskus Karsunke:Yes, i know ;)! But the posted code is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't tell how to implement the following steps but I think it's not too hard to find a solution on the net:

- acquire root-access for your application
- check if /system is mounted with option rw, if not, remount it so

hint: use the "adb shell" and check if the upper steps can lead to success
(su && remount -o remount,rw /system && touch /system/test)

On some devices there's the unlucky chance that the internal memory is in protected mode (google S-ON / S-OFF). If this is the case for you it will not be that easy like I imagined.
But even than it must be possible, since the market is installing files there. This would be the last hint, to look at the market source-code ;/

Comment: If your answer isn't complete and contains "I'm sure you can find a solution on the net", it should be posted as a comment.

Answer (score -1):

You need to call following method on file object

```
file.createNewFile();
```

On executing this following error comes because of read-only directory

```
11-09 19:45:15.136: E/VideoSample(4245): java.io.IOException: open failed: EROFS 
                    (Read-only file system)
11-09 19:45:15.136: E/VideoSample(4245):    at 
                     java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java:940)
```

Comment: So how to make it writable too ?