# File not created in /system directory

Tags: android, file

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Create a file in /system directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069125/create-a-file-in-system-directory)

First of all, i gave the application all superuser permission(i'm using my rooted Galaxy S), then i want  to create a file in /system using this code:

```
try 
{
 File file = new File("/system/", "test.prop");
 file.createNewFile();
 }
```

Unfortunately, the file is not created. What could be the source of the problem?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the /system partition is mounted as read-only in Android. You will have to re-mount it as read-write to be able to write to it. `adb remount` may help with that.

Comment: And how making it with JAVA code? IS there any guides ?

Comment: You could execute a shell from your app issuing a *mount* command. Before trying this note that the /system will most likely be mounted from a different partition on different devices, so you need to figure out the current mounted partition and then re-mount it as r/w. Afterall, it seems to me what you're trying to do has a bricking potential in excess of 90%.

Answer (score 1):

The system partition is read-only, so you can't write to it while it is still in that state.