# how to build a dir and file at /system file using code

Tags: android

my app have root right ,i want to using code to build a dir or file at /system  or  other dir of device.

i know common java build file as:

```
File file = new File(destFileName);
if (file.exists()) {
 return false;
}
```

if  i can build dir at system like the above code?if i need use su command before build file dir as

```
Process p = null; 
p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
```

edit: i have  read [Create a file in /system directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069125/create-a-file-in-system-directory)  but i cannot using code write :

```
 " hint: use the "adb shell" and check if the upper steps can lead to success (su && remount -o remount,rw /system && touch /system/test)"
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to get /system be mounted for write. By default it is read-only. You can use command like `mount -o remount,rw /system`
2. You can create dir using `mkdir` command
3. You can change the owner user by `chown` command
4. After that you can use java code as ususal.

Comment: @pengwang you should pass this commands to `su` binary to run them as root